# GraphQL Operation Name

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, graphql-js

When I'm setting up my GraphQL definitions on the back-end (i.e. Apollo), is there any way or any benefit to defining Operation Names?

For example, I have an update operation that can take an enum as a parameter:

```
mutation {
  updateOrder(status: StatusEnum): Order
}
```

But I was thinking that I could do specific named operations for each status, and the back-end resolvers being wired up to each (and subsequently knowing "OK I'm the cancel resolver, I don't need to care about some enum").

```
mutation {
  makeOrderCanceled(): Order
  makeOrderPending(): Order
  makeOrderComplete(): Order
}

resolvers = {
  makeOrderCanceled: () => {
    // don't need to infer the status from a param, in essence could 
    // just hardcode the enum here and prevent the API consumers from 
    // having to know about it.
  }
}
```

This is fine, and probably what I will do. But that leaves out the operation name. I've read that it's useful for logging, and comes in as a field on the actual HTTP request. That I understand. But if I'm defining my types, queries, and mutations *as a back-end developer*, is there anything I can be doing to help improve the intention and suggested use of my schema? For example, the last approach I could see is something like this:

```
mutation CancelOrder {
  updateOrder(status: "cancel"): Order   # this
  updateOrder(): Order                   # or this like the examples above
}

mutation CompleteOrder {
  updateOrder(status: "complete"): Order  # this
  updateOrder(): Order                    # or this like the examples above
}
```

**Questions**

- Can you define the operation name in the back-end definitions?
- If yes to the previous question, what's the benefit to doing so, specifically comparing example 2 and 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot define the operation name in the backend as the operations are dynamic and created by the consumers of your API. I believe your are mixing concepts here. However you decide to build your schema (`updateOrder` or `makeOrder****`), what your are ultimately saying is:

> Here are the mutations that this server can handle, have fun!

Your consumer can decide to issue any number of different query, so for example I could very well decide to do in one operation:

```
mutation TryToBreakAPI {
   makeOrderCanceled {
     id
   }
   makeOrderPending {
     id
   }
}
```

As per the graphql specification, mutations are executed in a sequential order (compared to queries that are executed in parallel), so it would first call the `makeOrderCanceled` resolver (and its children) then the `makeOrderPending` resolver (and its children).

Logging the operation name is still a good idea to enable easier debugging for private APIs since you can mandate your frontend engineers to write one so if a query fails it is easier to debug where it is coming from. But it is not a silver bullet so you should generally log the full query too (if just to catch some potential malicious actors who might try to use your API in an unexpected way).

There are ways to limit the queries that your server can accept, this is generally called `query whitelisting` and the implementation of it will depend on the server your use (you can even built yourself to be honest). It generally consist in doing a SHA256 of each query used in the frontend and telling the backend to only accept the queries that hash to one of the "approved" hashes.